# what is the meaning of parameters in display function in Joomla display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)

Tags: joomla

Hi i am new to Joomla just learning to create the components but there is some problems regarding the parameters cant figure out the exact working or use of these parameters, please help me out if u know the answer.

```
function display($catchable=false){
  JRequest :: setVar('view',JRequest::getcmd('view','dashboard'));
  parent:: display($catchable);                                                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

$cachable If true, the view output will be cached

more information you can read bellow link

http://docs.joomla.org/API15:JController/display